# Using C++ for loop to create different nodes of a linked list Class in the memory and how to return its head?

Tags: c++

When I run this, it prints the same addresses? Also, how can I return its starting or head? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;

        Node(int value){
             data = value;
        }
};

int main(){
    system("cls");

    Node* temp = nullptr;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        Node newNode(i);
        newNode.next = temp;
        temp = &newNode;
        cout<< &newNode << "\n"; //here it always prints the same addresses
    }
}
```

Comment: `newNode` is a block-scope local variable, it's created and destroyed every time through the loop. At the end of the loop, there are no instances of `Node` still alive - there is no list, and no head of that list. If you want an object to survive beyond the block where it's created, it has to be allocated dynamically, on the heap.

Comment: Thank you Sir. But how can I do that?

Comment: You may wish to read about operator `new` in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: if i will declare the newNode outside the loop, how can I create new nodes using loop?

Comment: In the manner explained in your favorite C++ textbook, in the chapter where it discusses operator `new`.